# PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR when using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, queue, rails-postgresql

When i run

```
$rspec "/any_file"
```

rspec loads in the schema.rb file to setup the database.

My understanding is that when it comes to this line

```
create_table "queue_classic_jobs", force: true do |t|; end
```

Rspec runs a

```
DROP TABLE "queue_classic_jobs"
```

command.

It trows this error

```
PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table queue_classic_jobs because 
other objects depend on it (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
DETAIL:  function lock_head(character varying) depends on type queue_classic_jobs
function lock_head(character varying,integer) depends on type queue_classic_jobs
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
: DROP TABLE "queue_classic_jobs"
```

It looks to me like I have to make rspec

```
DROP TABLE "queue_classic_jobs" CASCADE
```

But how?

Comment: Possible solution: in rails console run: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('DROP TABLE "queue_classic_jobs" CASCADE')`. This gets rid of the objects that depend on the table.

Answer (score 10):

Are you running Rails >= 4.1?  There's a new feature where ActiveRecord tries to keep your test schema in sync with schema.rb without reloading the entire database.  You can read about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#railties-notable-changes.

Unfortunately it doesn't work with foreign keys: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14708.  You can disable it by adding this line at the end of config/environments/test.rb:

```
config.active_record.maintain_test_schema = false
```

Comment: No, but I am upgrading to 4.1 in a few days. Will look into it then +1 for replying on a old question!